# Need way to provide Solr boost function in Django Haystack

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I need to provide my search results an edismax boost function `feed_count follower_count^8.0`, which should result in the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/ng_core/select?bf=feed_count%20follower_count%5E8.0&defType=edismax&q=shad
```

Closest I came by searching the docs and stackoverflow was to filter using `AltParser` like this:

```
sqs.filter(text=AltParser('edismax', query, bf='feed count follower_count^8.0')
```

which produces the following query:

```
{!edismax bf='feed count follower_count^8.0' }shad
```

which returns no result at all. I played around in Solr Dashboard and even if I get it to return results, the way Solr parses it is very very different than it does the expected query.

I tried reading upon how to add custom query params to the generated query, but the `Custom Input` method does not fit my need since it can only change the query text and not add parameters.

The current workaround I had to do was to do it this way:

```
sqs.query.get_results(defType='edismax', bf='feed_count')
```

So that the extra kwargs get passed on to the final query function, however, I really don't want to jump out of the nice SearchQuerySet chaining, and more importantly, I can't get the paging to work with this nicely:

```
sqs.query.get_results(defType='edismax', bf='feed_count')[offset:offset + page_size]
```

This won't work since the results have already been fetched, and

```
sqs[offset:offset + page_size].query.get_results(defType='edismax', bf='feed_count')
```

This won't work since now sqs slice returns a list.

To correctly run it, I have to write it like this:

```
query = sqs.query
query.set_limits(offset, offset + page_size)
query.get_results(defType='edismax', bf='feed_count')
```

Which feels slightly more hacky. So is there a way I can add query params without breaking the SearchQuerySet chain?